# Photoshop Scripting, Reopen Last Documents

Tags: photoshop, photoshop-script

I work with the same multiple files in Photoshop. When I close Photoshop, I would like it to remember all open documents and the way they were arranged. Then, the next time I open Photoshop, I would like it to restore all previously open files exactly how they were.

I have some programming experience, albeit a bit rusty. But before I tackle this problem, is scripting something like this in Photoshop possible?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of over-complicating things with scripts, I made an action that opens and arranges specific documents. Then I made a "Start Application" event under the File > Scripts > Scripts Event Manager that calls the action when Photoshop is opened.